Receiving an error UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL inside Jenkins using sf project deploy start command
Receiving an error UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL inside Jenkins using sf project deploy start command
sh "sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts --source-dir force-app/main/default --target-org ${SANDBOX}"

We don't understand why this is happening and how can we fix it or avoid this?

Looks like sometimes sf upgrades itself to prerelease version and this causes failures on non-preview sandboxes.
This is weird that version specified in the sfdx-project.json is not considered.
However, it is possible to override the version parameter using -a switch attribute.
So we can do that.
API_VERSION = sh(script: "cat ${BASE_DIR}/sfdx-project.json | jq '.sourceApiVersion' -r", returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "API Version: ${API_VERSION}"
sh "sf project deploy start -a ${API_VERSION} --ignore-conflicts --source-dir force-app/main/default --target-org ${SANDBOX}"

